# Is it possible to express a sum as a difference operation?

Tags: summation

In [the difference calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_calculus), the (forward) difference operator (which is usually taken to be the inverse of a summation) is defined as:
$$\Delta y(t)=y(t+1)-y(t)$$

Is it possible to express this operator as a summation of some function of $y(t)$?  In other words, can we express
$$\Delta y(t)=\sum{f(y(t))}$$

in the general case?

**I don't want any difference operators involved in the Summation.**

**Additionally, it may be the case that two or more seperate summations are required.  I will accept this as well.**

**I will accept an answer for the definite sum or the indefinite sum.**

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: Yes.  I've seen differentiation expressed as integration.  So I'm wondering if there is a method for it's discreet counterparts.

Comment: You seek a formula similar to $\Delta y(t)=\sum{f(y(t))}$. In the RHS, what is the range of the summation? Note that one cannot sum over $t$ since $t$ appears on the LHS. Thus, at present the formula you suggest makes no sense.

Comment: @Did I think he means the indefinite sum.

Comment: I'm interested in both the definite and indefinite sum.  If anyone can provide the definite sum I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: @MattGroff You do not seem extremely interested in giving a precise meaning to your question... As I said, at the moment the formula you proposed makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is $f(y(t)) = \Delta \Delta y(t)$.

It's rather like trying to take the derivative $f'(x)$ of a function $f(x)$ and find the function that that function is the integral of. The only way to do that is to take the second derivative $f''(x)$.

Comment: Now, if I'm wrong, and you have seen differentiation expressed as integration in another way, I'd be obliged if you could show me, and I could modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: In fact I have, and on this site too.  Unfortunately, I don't remember the reference, but I will hunt for it.  That is indeed what I am after.

Comment: Yes, but $\Delta$ isn't a function(on N).

Comment: Whatever function can take $y(t)$ and return $\Delta \Delta y(t)$ for all $t$, then.

Comment: It's a function on the set of functions from N to R not a function on N.